# Load front page inside an iframe

Tags: drupal-7

Objective:

When you create a new node you have the possibility of "previewing" said created node. Now, I have been asked to modify this so that the "preview" shows the front page with the newly "publish to front page" node added.

I thought I could approach this two ways:

1) Manage to programmatically load drupal's front page inside an iframe. I have tried looking through code from other modules such as [Page Previewer](https://drupal.org/project/pagepreview) but can't seem to find a base on which to start. This means not only loading the front page, but also adding the newly created node to it to see how it displays.

2) Making new content published to the front page only visible to admins until they decide to make it public to the users.

Thanks!

Comment: So simply outputting an iframe element with it’s `src` attribute set to the address of the front page doesn’t work? Then you’ll have to be more specific as to the why not.

Comment: Don't know what went through my mind, I'll edit the question!